# Jquery Cookie plugin doesn't load in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, cookies, jquery-cookie

I've got a wordpress site with jquery cookie plugin installed. It used to work fine. For a little while, i've been working with a content that didn't require the plugin. Meanwhile, i've started using cloudflare.

Today, I tried adding content that utilizes that plugin, and suddenly got an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: $.cookie is not a function".

Obviously, the plugin is not loading. What i've done first is, i've moved that plugin from a separate file into header. Right above the script that utilizes it. No luck. I figured, it could still be showing cloudflare cached version, so, i've deleted cache and minified scripts & css. Still no luck. And now I'm stuck.

I know that people here like some code to be provided, but as you can understand, there is a lot of it.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that $.cookie is being called before it is loaded? Or that CloudFlare force the loading of a jQuery asset whose version isn't compatible with your cookie plugin?

Comment: just double checked. $.cookie is being called on click, and i made sure the page is loaded before clicked. If that's what you mean.  And could you elaborate on the later part. Can CloudFlare pull assets from some other place rather than my site? p.s. i know it's not encouraged here, but any way. here is a live link. http://playmember.com/questions/the-best-age-to-adopt-a-puppy-is-at/  $.cookie is called on one of the answers click

Comment: I was thinking maybe Cloud override your jQuery with a version that doesn't work with your plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like disabling cloud flare took a while. Works fine now.